# Interpreter crashes trying to use tkinter library

Tags: python, tkinter, macos-big-sur, python-3.9

I have tried to staring the application in VSCODE by Python3.
This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.mainloop()
```

only 3 lines `:))`, but when I'm trying to execute the file in terminal it will give me an error, which you can see below.

```
arash@Arash-MacBook-Pro tkinter % python3 main.py 
macOS 11 or later required !
zsh: abort ------ python3 main.py
arash@Arash-MacBook-Pro tkinter %
```

My Mac worked on "Big Sur" and has Python3.9.

Comment: <p>
Hi Arash, What is your current macOS Version? As the error message tells you, macOS 11 or later required <p/>

Comment: @SaadWetas, my macOS is 'Big Sur'

Comment: @GinoMempin, sorry that was only to separate the lines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an issue in the way `brew` installs Python ([source](https://bugs.python.org/issue42480)). If you install Python directly via the official installer [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) then `tkinter` should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed python using brew you can also use the following command to install the missing package:

```
brew install python-tk@3.9
```