# python aborts when calling method in turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I am just trying to do some learning with turtle. But for some reason I get this error message when trying to import and run the script:

```
macOS 11 or later required !
[1]    1673 abort      python3 day16_turtle.py
```

Here is the code I tried to run:

```
import turtle

timmy = turtle.Turtle()

print(timmy)
```

I can import turtle normal but when I try to run this line it gives me the above error to `timmy = turtle.Turtle()`

Also, the VS Code shows the below 3 messages:

```
GIT_ASKPASS=/private/var/folders/qz/1q1pzc_13tng37ltmc0r3gz40000gn/T/AppTranslocation/A692D70A-09BC-4A39-A204-0526042BE3EB/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh
VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE=/private/var/folders/qz/1q1pzc_13tng37ltmc0r3gz40000gn/T/AppTranslocation/A692D70A-09BC-4A39-A204-0526042BE3EB/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Renderer).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Renderer)
VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN=/private/var/folders/qz/1q1pzc_13tng37ltmc0r3gz40000gn/T/AppTranslocation/A692D70A-09BC-4A39-A204-0526042BE3EB/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass-main.js
```

Also, my mac produces a problem report (which I won't post it here, see photo):
[image]

Does anyone know why is this??
I'm using MacOS 11.1, VS Code, Python 3.9

Comment: You will need to also show the code you're attempting to run.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just added :)

Comment: It honestly looks like there's something wrong with your Python/Tkinter installation, since the same code (aside from a typo fix) works fine for me.

Comment: hum... any idea on how to re-install to make sure it's right?

Comment: I narrowed down the abort error happens at line: 
timmy = turtle.Turtle()

Comment: have you tried running it in other IDEs such as pycharm community edition? It may have to do with your environment.

Comment: I tried running this on my terminal and gives me the same error. So it's not an IDE issue?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's a known issue with the way brew installs Python and doesn't support tkinter on macOS 11. I am just going to wait for a fix and hopefully it will be solved next `brew update && upgrade` I do.
Reference here: [Interpreter crashes trying to use tkinter library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65315077/interpreter-crashes-trying-to-use-tkinter-library)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Solved it by installing Python3.9.1 directly from python.org (uninstalling existing 3.9 not required).